# ROS Answers emails

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get ROS Answers to send an email when a question is posted with a specific tag?

Update: Where is the tags listed in 'allow only selected tags' set?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9204/ros-answers-emails/) by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 403 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-26**:
We're testing a script to inject tags into the ontology.  Right now I've injected tags for all the packages in ros-diamondback-desktop.  I'm waiting for the dust to settle before I give it a more mammoth list of tags (probably every package, stack, and repo)

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2011-02-26**:
Also it is not possible to filter on a tag that does not exist. For example adding a tag 'iheart-ros-pkg' is forgotten because there are currently no posts that have that tag

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2011-02-26**:
The solution doesn't work if no tags are selected and it is set to only email posts with selected tags.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-25**:
This looks like a duplicate of a previous question. How can I mark this as a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/35/how-to-get-notified-of-new-questions-with-a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.  Go to your profile page and click 'subscriptions'.  Then choose "allow only selected tags" along with the frequency options.

"Selected tags" == "interesting tags" that shows up in your right-hand sidebar when normally viewing the site.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1